# Как отсортировать массив обьектов?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов :

```
a = [
  {
    name: '2107',
    id: '1',
    sup: undefined,

  },
  {
    name: '2',
    id: '2',
    sup: {
      name: "name1"
    }
  },
  {
    name: '21',
    id: '3',
    sup: {
      name: "name2"
    }
  }
]
```

Как отсортировать, так чтобы сначала были элементы, где `sup` не `undefined`, а потом уже равны `undefined`. Т.е. вот так:

```
а = [
  {
    name: '2',
    id: '2',
    sup: {
      name: "name1"
    }
  },
  {
    name: '21',
    id: '3',
    sup: {
      name: "name2"
    }
  },
  {
    name: '2107',
    id: '1',
    sup: undefined,

  }
]
```

Пробовал вот так(не работает):

```js
function sortBy(arr) {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => a.sup != undefined ? 1 : -1);
}

sortBy(totalArr);
```

Comment: _где sup не undefined,а потом уже пустые_ и ниже пример противоположный словам... Вам как надо то?

Comment: В вашем примере есть синтаксические ошибки. И это сбивает с толку. И support или sup?

Comment: @InDevX, Александр Ищенко , поправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let obj = [{
    name: '2107',
    id: '1',
    sup: undefined,
  },{
    name: '2',
    id: '2',
    sup: {name:"name1"}
  },{  name: '21',
     id: '3',
     sup: {name:"name2"}
  }
];

Array.prototype.sortByField = function(field) {
  return this.slice(0).sort(function(a,b) {
    return (a[field] !== undefined) ? -1 : 1;
  });
}

console.log(obj.sortByField('sup'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Сначалa сортируются ключи или ID, Затем создается новый массив согласно упорядоченности ключей.

Ниже пример сортировки по полю ID

```
 var key = [];
    var nArray = [];
    var a = [{
            name: '2107',
            id: 3,
            sup: 'undefined'
        },
        {
            name: '2107',
            id: 5,
            sup: 'undefined'
        },
        {name: '2107',
            id: 1,
            sup: 'undefined'
        },
    ];

    a.forEach(function (item) {
        key.push(item.id);
    });

    key.sort();

    key.forEach(function (key) {
        a.forEach(function (item) {
            if (item.id == key) {
                nArray.push(item);
            }
        });
    });
    
    console.info(nArray);
```